# SQL Server Get Max

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have the following table:

```
ID  Date   FirstName  Dept
1   1/2/12 James      Act
1   2/5/12 Mike       IT
2   5/6/12 Joe        HR
2   7/6/12 Keith      IT
```

What I need to do that for each ID, I need to get the max date.
I need to show ID, Date, FirstName, Dept for the record for each ID that has the Max Date.
So in this case for ID of 1, I would show 1 2/5/12 Mike IT 
How do I do this in SQL Server T-SQL?

I know I need to do group by.

The table name is TblAct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will use the `MAX()` function with a `GROUP BY`

```
select t1.id, t1.date, t1.fname, t1.dept
from tblAct t1
inner join
(
  SELECT Max(Date) maxdate, ID
  from TblAct
  GROUP BY id
) t2
  on t1.id = t2.id
  and t1.date = t2.maxdate
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5b4f7/5)

Comment: bluefoot, please look at what I revised. Thank you

Comment: is there a way to do this in one select vs inner join?

Comment: is there a way to do this in one select vs inner join?

Comment: @NathanP is there a reason to not user an inner join?

Comment: I have a monster select statement. I would just prefer to do it in one select if possible. What I have above is a very simplied version

Comment: if you need other columns that are not similar, then you will need to join or use a sub-select.

Comment: bluefeet, I posted another one with a more elaborate sql that I am working on. It doesn't seem to be working

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with windows/ranking functions:

```
select ID, Date, FirstName, Dept
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by date desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1
```

This is ordering all the rows for each id by date, in reverse order.  It then selects the first of them.

Answer (score 0):

dont use group by :

```
select * from tblAct t1
where date=(select max(date) from tblAct where t1.id = id)
```

just enjoy.